# ruby function definition doesn't work

Tags: ruby, function

I just started ruby, and I have this code in file `ex6.rb`:

```
class Newclass
  def funct()
    puts "inside funct"
  end
end
```

When I try to run this from command prompt using command:  `ex6.rb`, it does not print any thing.  How am I suppose dto define a function in a file to be able to run it from command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define a class and a method... But you are not calling it. You need to add a call like:

```
NewClass.new.funct
```

In order to see your text printed.

Comment: Or `inst = Newclass.new` followed by `inst.funct`.  By the way, they are called _methods_ in ruby.